# Transforming null into empty string in javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

Hi can I transfrom the null string into empty string ?

I have a sample data like this

```
'To':['test@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com','null','test3@gmail.com','null','null']


let toEmailAddress = _.toString(To)
```

and now it will become

```
toEmailAddress  =
'test@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com','null','test3@gmail.com','null','null'
```

How can I check or replace the 'null' into empty string or empty?

I know im gonna use `_.replace` or javascript `.replace` but I dont know how

and my final output that I need to solve is looks like this

```
toEmailAddress  =
'test@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com','test3@gmail.com'
```

Comment: `toEmailAddress  =
'test@gmail.com','...` is invalid syntax... is that meant to be an array, or a larger string? (if array, need `[`, if string, need delimiters around the entire string)

Comment: `str == 'null' ? '' : str`

Comment: @CertainPerformance actually its an array and I changed it into string :)

Comment: Please edit your question so that the syntax of the result and expected output is correct.

Comment: @gdoron should I use replace javascript ?

Comment: @CertainPerformance can you please help me to elaborate ? its a javascript syntax, and I have declare there's a array on the top of the sentence

Comment: Your current `toEmailAddress = 'test@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com','null','test3@gmail.com','null','null'` results in the variable `toEmailAddress` holding the string `'null'`, because you're invoking the comma operator, which surely isn't desirable. Please declare `toEmailAddress` as the actual output you want, in whichever format you want - it's not so clear at the moment. If you want an array, you need an array delimiter right after the `=`. If you want a string, you need a string delimiter right after the `=` (with each delimiter ending at the end of the line)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using lodash, you can use [_.filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#filter) (or plain old [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter))

What you want to achieve is filtering out **noisy** values and only keeping **good** ones. You can use the following:

`_.filter(['test@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com','null','test3@gmail.com','null','null'], v => v && v !== 'null')` which will give you `['test@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com','test3@gmail.com']`.

Without using lodash, you can use the following: `['test@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com','null','test3@gmail.com','null','null'].filter(v => v && v !== 'null')`

Comment: + 1 for this Thanks man! question what if there's['test@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com','null','test3@gmail.com','null','null',,,,,,,,,'test123@gmail.com'] . can I also change the comma's into empty ? or same output of 
['test@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com','test3@gmail.com', 'test123@gmail.com']

Comment: @MikeVictoria try it and see what happens. Array.filter/lodash.filter actually let you check each value of your array. Only values that you specifically choose are kept. `v=> v && v !=='null'ˋ means that values should not be null,undefined,false,0, empty string or a string 'null'

Comment: sorry man, actually my question is already solve on  your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript [Array::filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to eliminate `'null'` strings, example:

```js
const input = ['test@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com','null','test3@gmail.com','null',,,,'null'];

let res = input.filter(x => x !== 'null');
console.log(res.join(","));
```

Comment: + 1 for this Thanks man! question what if there's['test@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com','null','test3@gmail.com','null','null',,,,,,,,,'test123@gmail.com'] . can I also change the comma's into empty ? or same output of ['test@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com','test3@gmail.com', 'test123@gmail.com']

Comment: @MikeVictoria How is exactly your input, an array with `empty strings` and `'null'` strings and you want to filter they both?

Comment: @MikeVictoria filter method already remove `holes` from the `input` array. I update the input to show that. Actually, most built-in array functions (like `forEach()`, `find()`, `reduce()`, etc) skips `holes` when iterating over the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
To = ['test@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com','null','test3@gmail.com','null','null',,,,,,,,,'test123@gmail.com'] ;
```

`toEmailAddress = _.toString(To)` becomes below:

```
'test@gmail.com,test2@gmail.com,null,test3@gmail.com,null,null,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,test123@gmail.com'
```

With replace you can use below

```
toEmailAddress.replace(/(null|undefined)\s*,\s*/g, '')
```

result would be below string if you want it back as Array just use `split(',')` on the resultant string

```
'test@gmail.com,test2@gmail.com,test3@gmail.com,test123@gmail.com'
```

Comment: + 1 for this Thanks man! question what if there's['test@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com','null','test3@gmail.com','null','null',,,,,,,,,'test123@gmail.com'] . can I also change the comma's into empty ? or same output of ['test@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com','test3@gmail.com', 'test123@gmail.com']

Comment: Thanks Man will check on this snippet :) thank you again :)